# HQL join on a list, but reversed

Tags: hibernate, hql

Let's say I have two tables, `Devices` and `Zones`. a zone has a list of users, and a device only has one zone.

I am able to do `SELECT d FROM Devices d INNER JOIN FETCH d.Zones WHERE ...` and it works.

But is it possible to the reverse ? I mean something like `SELECT z FROM Zones z INNER JOIN z.Devices WHERE ...`. Because this one doesn't work.

(Sorry if the question seems dumb, but I am learning how to use Hibernate and I can't find the answer.)

Comment: I would suggest you post your entities so we can see how you've mapped those entities. It should be possible, you can do bidirectional mapping in hibernate. [Here's an example](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-onetomany-bidirectional-relationship/)

Comment: these are the two entities, as simple as that : a device has an ID and a zone, a zone has an ID and a list of devices. (to learn, the simpler the better right ?). I'll give a look at your link, thank you